# How do I know if my code that uses Azure Storage is to be affected by upcoming API versions removal in December 2015?

Tags: api, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I've got an [email from Microsoft](http://aka.ms/Qga48e) saying lower versions of Storage Service are going to be removed in December 2015.

Our applications use Azure SDK 1.8 and 2.0.

How do we check for sure if we're impacted by this change?

Comment: A nearly-identical question was just posted a day or two ago. And no versions of the "service" are being removed. It's about API versioning.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: Well, although the service is being preserved, a certain way of using it (which is using certain versions of the API) *is* being removed. So although users don't need to find alternatives to Azure Storage they might need to ensure that they still can use the service after Dec 2015.

Comment: Right - but it's an important difference. As posted in the other question, the OP assumed the "Storage Service" was going away and needed to be replaced by the File Service. That's why I added the clarification.

Comment: How could we find which version of storage services we are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to interpret the details in that letter (not clear if the lowest required SDK version is 2.0 or 2.1), so the best bet is to validate it yourself. Start Fiddler and run the code in question and see which `x-ms-version` headers are attached to the request.

For example, you might try `CloudBlob.DownloadToFile()`. Fiddler will show a request like this:

```
GET /path/to/specific/blob/here?timeout=600 HTTP/1.1
```

and among the request headers you might see this (if you use SDK 1.8)

```
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18
```

which means that the code targets API version `2011-08-18`. Since the earliest API version that will be kept is `2012-02-12` that would mean you're affected.

I'm not sure about SDK 2.0 but you can easily check it yourself using the same technique.