# Changing version of Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am a beginner in Azure and have come across a task to change the storage version.I basically found that the versions are obsolete and need to upgrade them as per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/08/05/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal.aspx

So, in one of the paragraphs its mentioned

**"What to change**

If you find any log entries which show that version to be removed is being used, you will need to find that component and either validate that it will continue to work (unversioned requests may continue to work as their implicit version will simply increase – see above), or take appropriate steps to change the version being used. Most commonly, one of the following two steps will be used:

1) Change the version specified in the request, typically by migrating to a later version of the libraries/tools. When possible, migrate to the latest version to get the most improvements and fixes.

2) Set the default service version to one of the supported versions now so that the behavior can be verified prior to removal. This only applies to anonymous requests with no explicit version. "

Question is, how to go about implementing point 1 and 2 ?

Thanks

Comment: Does your service use Azure SDK? Which language is it written in?

Comment: Yes..i do use. Its written in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code is written in C# and uses Azure SDK your best bet is to upgrade it to a "new enough" SDK. [It's unclear whether version 2.0 or 2.1 is the lowest required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442919/57428). So your route is the following:

First, check if you really have to do anything.

1. You check which Azure SDK your service uses. If it's 2.1 or higher you don't need to worry yet. If your're unsure - use Fiddler to validate the version headers as explained in the linked to post.
2. If you use Azure SDK 2.0 you'd better check the version headers as explained in the linked to post.
3. If you use Azure SDK prior to 2.0 you are surely affected and have to upgrade.

So if you found you do need to upgrade you'll have to download and install the newer SDK and then remove references to old SDK assemblies from your projects and add references to new SDK assemblies. Then you try to build your code and maybe fix a lot of calls because SDK interfaces have changed (that's what I see migrating from 1.8 to 2.4). Once it builds you test it works fine and then you remove the old SDK version to ensure the code builds without it present.

There was a breaking change between 2.1 and 2.2 - the latter only support Visual Studio 2012 and higher. There was another set of changes in Azure Diagnostics functioning between 2.4 and 2.5 which are so long to read that I chose to migrate to 2.4 instead of 2.5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Can we try this alternative ? Can we check the x-ms-version of the storage api's with the help of fiddler. I have found this document here to do this. Is it any different ?    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/08/04/what-s-the-deal-with-x-ms-version.aspx

Comment: @SandyW That's exactly what I'm suggesting.